# plotting a SpatialPolygons object using lines() without lines connecting separate polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is almost an extension of a question asked on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196440/extract-feature-coordinates-from-spatialpolygons-and-other-sp-classes), so I'll use the demo dataset from there.

I'm attempting to plot these polygons with lines(), so I can overlay these with an image.plot. To do this, I use fortify, like so

```
    # taken from the linked stackoverflow question
    Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
    Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
    Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
    Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

    Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
    Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
    Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
    SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

    image.plot(x = c(0:10), y = c(0:10), z = matrix(runif(100, 0,1), nrow = 10),
        col = terrain.colors(20)) # fake data so lines() plays nice.
    lines(fortify(SpP))
    # there's a weird line connecting the square island in the middle to the polygon surrounding it
```

What I would like to get is an image like this, which I can produce with ggplot...

```
    require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = fortify(SpP)) + geom_path()
```

I can see two possible solutions to this, either an analog to the "group =" argument in the aes() call in ggplot(), or some way to get fortify to insert 'NA' between different groups (this is what the lines() function interprets as breaks). I can produce an effect manually, but I couldn't do this with the real dataset.

```
    SpP3 <- rbind(SpP2[1:5,], rep(NA, 7), SpP2[6:10,], rep(NA, 7), SpP2[10:14,], rep(NA, 7), SpP2[15:19,])
    image.plot(x = c(0:10), y = c(0:10), z = matrix(runif(100, 0,1), nrow = 10), col = terrain.colors(20))
    lines(SpP3)
```

edit: I'd like to be able to produce these plots using image.plot, since it's faster for my real dataset, and I will be more compatible with what others I'm working with are using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, time to go home...

```
    image.plot(x = c(0:10), y = c(0:10), z = matrix(runif(100, 0,1), nrow = 10),
    col = terrain.colors(20)) # fake data so lines() plays nice.
    plot(SpP)
```